# Load data from multiple dataframes containing both path and labels in keras

Tags: keras, dataframe, image-preprocessing

I am aware that there exists a function in `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` called `flow_from_dataframe`. But this function assumes that we have one dataframe containing all the paths to the images and labels associated with it. But what if we have multiple dataframes and we want to use these dataframes on a per-epoch basis so that in each epoch we can load a different dataframe and the labels and images associated with it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write your own generator.

Comment: Yeah i did that, but i would prefer a builtin function provided by library or framework as it reduces the scope of mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the training will continue if you don't recompile and we put dataset only in the last step.

*So, something similar to this snippet should work*

```py
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255, shear_range = 0.2, horizontal_flip = True)

training_set_1 = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, color_mode='grayscale',target_size = (28, 28,1), batch_size = 2)
training_set_2 = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, color_mode='grayscale',target_size = (28, 28,1), batch_size = 2)

model = keras.models.Sequential([ ... ])

optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.2, momentum=0.9, decay=0.01)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=["accuracy"])

for i in list(range(10)):
    history = model.fit(training_set_1,epochs=1)
    history = model.fit(training_set_2,epochs=1)
```

Definitely, learning can be very noisy based on the difference in variance in datagens.

 Also,history will be reset everytime.

Comment: Cool, yeah the training is never forfited until we recompile the model, in which case we get a new model name. This should work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But I guess the callbacks like EarlyStop might not work in this scenario....Let me know if there is a way to make EarlyStop in this case

Comment: You can check the loss(can get loss from history)/patience counter and break the loop after a certain count. A better option - Create custom callback - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55892107/2187625 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915771/keras-earlystopping-based-on-user-input